# Retrieve fields from database without emulating them?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small test program in ASP.NET MVC4 which allows you to select items from a dropdown menu. It uses `Json` and `JavaScript` (I'm not familiar with these at all).

Here's the code I have at the moment:

**HomeController**:

```
        public ActionResult CountryList()
        {
            IQueryable countries = Country.GetCountries();

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new SelectList(
                            countries,
                            "CountryCode",
                            "CountryName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );
            }

            return View(countries);
        }

        public ActionResult StateList(string CountryCode)
        {
            IQueryable states = State.GetStates().Where(x => x.CountryCode == CountryCode);

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new SelectList(
                                states,
                                "StateID",
                                "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );

            return View(states);
        }
```

**View**:

```
@section scripts { 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Home/Countries/List", function (data) {
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    items += "<option value='" + country.Value + "'>" + country.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Countries").html(items);
            });

            $("#Countries").change(function () {
                $.getJSON("/Home/States/List/" + $("#Countries > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                    var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                        items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#States").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label for="Countries">Countries</label>
    <select id="Countries" name="Countries"></select>
    <br /><br />
    <label for="States">States</label>
    <select id="States" name="States"></select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and finally the **Models**:

**Country**

```
    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<Country> GetCountries()
        {
            return new List<Country>
            {
                new Country {
                    CountryCode = "CA",
                    CountryName = "Canada"
                },
                new Country{
                    CountryCode = "US",
                    CountryName = "United-States"
                }
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

**State**:

```
public class State
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<State> GetStates()
    {
        return new List<State>
        {
            new State
                {
                    CountryCode = "CA",
                    StateID=1,
                    StateName = "Ontario"
                },
            new State
                {
                    CountryCode = "CA",
                    StateID=2,
                    StateName = "Quebec"
                },
            new State
                {
                    CountryCode = "CA",
                    StateID=3,
                    StateName = "Nova Scotia"

                    // .. and so on

                }.AsQueryable();

        }
    } 
}
```

**My question is**: how do I make this solution work with a database table? What do I need to do in order to make this same dropdown work with fields from a database? Does anyone have any useful tutorials that they could recommend?

Comment: What ORM do you use to access the database?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov I'm not sure what that means (sorry I'm new to this) however in order to make a database, I chose SQL Server Database (if that's what you meant). From there I can create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: @BorisSmith If you go to official MVC site, there are alot of learning resources that cover database access using Entity Framework Code First.  There is also a link to a free trial of very good training videos.  Go here and click **Learn**: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose how you will access your database. There are a lot of options, but I recommend you to use some kind of [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It's not easy to choose an ORM too. So you will need to do a research before and find one that fits your needs best. As you wrote in comment you are new to this, so I will provide few samples of how fetching of `States` might look in different ORM's.

**[Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)** - ORM used on this (SO) site.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("CONN_STR"))
{
    IList<State> states = conn
        .Query<State>(
            "select * States where CountryCode = @CountryCode",
            new { CountryCode = countryCode })
        .ToList();
}
```

As you can see here we just provide SQL and object with object with parameters and Dapper does all things for us. We get list of entities.

**[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)** - ORM created by Microsoft.

```
IList<State> states = 
    DbContext.States.Where(state => state.CountryCode == countryCode).ToList();
```

You don't need to write any SQL at all, we are using pure LINQ syntax.

Of course all ORM's has their pros and cons, so again, you need to do a research before.

**EDIT**: It seems that you have problems with filling selects... Then first you will need to create correct models for EF. You can reuse your existing models, just add some attributes:

```
[Table("Countries")]
public class Country
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}


[Table("States")]
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

In `Table` attribute you should use your real table names of course. Then you need to create `DbContext`:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to specify connection string in web.config like in tutorial.

I simplified methods for getting countries and states and now they return only JSON:

```
public ActionResult CountryList()
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var countries = db.Countries.ToList();
        return Json(
            new SelectList(countries, "CountryCode", "CountryName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public ActionResult StateList(string countryCode)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var states = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode)
            ? db.States.Where(state => state.CountryCode == countryCode).ToList()
            : new List<State>();
        return Json(
            new SelectList(states, "StateID", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

It's a good idea to move DB access code to different class but I hope you can do it yourself.

You had some strange URl's in you javascript so here is working example:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/CountryList", function (data) {
    // Same code that you have
});

$("#Countries").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/StateList?countryCode=" + $("#Countries > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
        // Same code that you have
    });
});
```

Comment: So if I make a new table in my database and fill in the fields: CountryCode, StateID and StateName. How would I be able to get access to these fields and place them into my dropdown menu? `IList<State> states = 
    DbContext.States.Where(state => state.CountryCode == countryCode).ToList();`? Like that? or am I missing something?

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683942/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-for-understanding-E) might be a good start for you.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. I've used it before and successfully implemented this into another project that I am currently working on however, I still do not fully understand how to fully implement it into a dropdown. Would you be able to modify your answer using the example from the tutorial link you just used? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I added more info, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the list of countries or states from a database then what you need to do is be able to query the database.  See these examples of using ado.net to query a database.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dw70f090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Then just change your .GetCountries and GetStates to get the list from the database.  The code will look something like this (this is just pseudocode)

```
var List<States> l = new List<States>();
while(reader.read()){
    var s = new State{
            CountryCode = reader["cc_code"],
            StateID=reader["stateId"],
            StateName = reader["stateName"]
    };
    l.add(s);
}

return l;
```

Comment: I've used this in the past: http://pastebin.com/bqc7i8a2 Can I do something similar to that? Obviously changing the `ss.SystemUsers.Add(users)` to something else. With `SystemUsers` referring to the database table. Do you understand what I mean?