# Asp.net mvc 5 renders a partial view after selecting one value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

*Asp.net mvc 5 renders a partial view after selecting one value by clicking submit on the cascading combobox*.

I am in a learning process so I apologize if off topic. I have my first question in SO regarding dropdown or combobox. Link that illustrate the code I'm using: [Retrieve fields from database without emulating them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538635/retrieve-fields-from-database-without-emulating-them).

How do I render a partial view (`StateId=1 Partial View`, `StateId=2 Partial View`, etc) if the condition is met after I click "submit"?

In other words if I pick Canada as the Country and in the second list I choose Ontario (`StateId=1`), how can I make it go to one partial page where I have Ontario's demographic info (for instance).

Thanks in advance. By the way I have these dropdown lists implemented inside a modal popup window but is not relevant right now (I will post it later for those interested).

The Controller, View and Models are identical to the link I provided (Having trouble posting the code).

```
public ActionResult CountryList()
    {
        IQueryable countries = Country.GetCountries();

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(
                        countries,
                        "CountryCode",
                        "CountryName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
        }

        return View(countries);
    }

    public ActionResult StateList(string CountryCode)
    {
        IQueryable states = State.GetStates().Where(x => x.CountryCode == CountryCode);

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new SelectList(
                            states,
                            "StateID",
                            "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );

        return View(states);
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to post some code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a partial view? One way to solve this would be using the StateId as the value for a form, adding a submit button, and make the form call an action in your controller, that then renders the view you want, based on the `StateId` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the neg

Comment: Why partial view? I'm using this approach to access different parts of my site which is group a Views each containing several partial views. The "success" combination on the cascading will take the user to that particular "department". Will post a sample once I learn to handle the posting issues.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Can you post a little sample code based on my question. What I'm really trying to achieve is to use this cascading DDL method to navigate around. It looks nice mounted in a modal popup. Thanks in advance. I know I could use DDL Navigation Menu instead.

Comment: Well I finally made it: I tried with New York State first and worked fine. I replaced the existing select at the Html.BeginForm with : <select id="States" onchange='location.href = this.value'>. Changed StateID from "int" to "string" at the State.cs and change StatedID=1 to StateID="States/NewYork", Created a StateController and from there I added a View to the StateController (named NewYork). That's all. Will do the same with other States. I still cannot manage to post codes here, sorry.